# unable to start CA server in Fabric first-network with latest version

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger-composer

I had completed building first-network in Hyper Ledger fabric and trying to create block chain network on the network i created using below tutorial.

https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org.html

In the middle, i found an option seems to be not working

[image: CA server start option]

I checked the bynf.sh file for the respective option since it seems to be showing error while executing and there is no such thing -a as argument provided for the script according to the script.

I have ignored the option and continued the tutorial and struck while installing network at Step 11.

[image: Command to install Network for Org1]

Here is the error i am getting

```
venkat@venkatltop:~/fabric-samples/first-network$ composer network install --card PeerAdmin@byfn-network-org1 --archiveFile trade-network.bna

⠙ Installing business network. This may take a minute...(node:17323) [DEP0079] DeprecationWarning: Custom inspection function on Objects via .inspect() is deprecated
⠹ Installing business network. This may take a minute...E0511 16:22:41.448320702   17323 ssl_transport_security.cc:989] Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed.
E0511 16:22:41.448766436   17323 ssl_transport_security.cc:989] Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed.
E0511 16:22:41.449125748   17323 ssl_transport_security.cc:989] Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed.
E0511 16:22:41.452536325   17323 ssl_transport_security.cc:989] Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed.
⠸ Installing business network. This may take a minute...E0511 16:22:41.628664154   17323 ssl_transport_security.cc:989] Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed.
E0511 16:22:41.632493135   17323 ssl_transport_security.cc:989] Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed.
✖ Installing business network. This may take a minute...
Error: Error trying install business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: Connect Failed
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: Connect Failed
Command failed
venkat@venkatltop:~/fabric-samples/first-network$
```

I believe that option -a may be linked to this error since it starts CA server in previous version which can avoid this error but not sure.

Please suggest me any solution to resolve this error.

Note: I had checked the solution from below link but the changes did not resolved my issue

[Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50006049/handshake-failed-with-fatal-error-ssl-error-ssl)

Comment: which github repo (URL) did you clone your `fabric-samples` from? Have you modified the Fabric configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If one had tried every solution mentioned from above answers but still getting the same error. Please verify your node version using `node --version` command. 
If it is the latest i.e.,10.0.0 or any other than 8.X version then changed to 8.X version to resolve this error.

My issue has been resolved when I changed to version 8.11.2

**Steps to change the node version using nvm :**

- Check for nvm availability using `nvm --version`
- If not available install nvm using below

`wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.0/install.sh | bash
source ~/.bashrc
nvm --version`

After nvm successfully installed, Now we will proceed to install 8.11.2 version

    `nvm install 8.11.2
    nvm alias default 8.11.2
    node -v`

If last command to retreive node version returned 8.11.2 as result then it is success. 
Now you can proceed to run `composer network install command` successfully.

NOTE:
The process shown above permenantly changes the node version if you just want to change temporarily use `nvm use 8.11.2` and it will reset once you exit the session.

---

gRPC is a modern, open source remote procedure call (RPC) framework that can run anywhere. It enables client and server applications to communicate transparently and makes it easier to build connected systems.

gRPC also provides npm module support. This module is not available in the prerequisites of Fabric or Composer but Composer internally using this package as one of its dependency.

It seems to be gRPC version that composer installed is not supporting to higher versions of node i.e., >8.X versions.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely you are using the standard fabric-samples,
In the pre-requisites section it states the following

> Next, clone the following GitHub Fabric Samples repository using the  command line (do not use the samples from the Fabric site: as it is missing some changes that are required for this tutorial)
>   Copy
>
> git clone -b issue-6978 https://github.com/sstone1/fabric-samples.git

This version adds in the fabric-ca's which are missing from the byfn sample provided by hyperledger fabric.

Comment: I used the same git repo. now, I can able to run the server with '-a' (CA server) option. but, the Handshake failed error still reproducing.  I had followed the same tutorial and no customizations done in it. Please tell me if any configurations need to be updated in that tutorial.

Comment: If you have run the generate command again, then the connection profiles and any card files you have created and imported into your card store will not be valid. You will need to recreate them all (and clear out your card store) following the steps of the tutorial as all the certificate information will have changed.

Comment: I have again downloaded all the docker images after removing old images.
Generated certificates again, tried the same process again but ended up with the same error as mentioned earlier.